# Visual Studio Code keeps reverting to old update

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been a user of Visual Studio Code on Windows for about 3 months, and recently I've discovered a serious issue.

Ever since the November 2020 update, whenever I close my Visual Studio Code tab and then reopen it, it shows me the July 2020 update screen. It seems to revert as well, as it then doesn't show me the run/debug buttons and F5 no longer works as well.

When I hit "Help", I'm able to restart to update, then it shows me the November 2020 update screen and everything works normally again. But then the next time I close the tab and reopen it, it reverts again.

I have looked at the Visual Studio Code website and found nothing about this problem, and I've already reinstalled Visual Studio Code once. I have no antiviruses currently.

How can I prevent this from happening?

UPDATE: I reported the issue as J. M. Arnold suggested, and the developers suggested a complete uninstall and reinstall. I did as they asked and now it is working perfectly! I think what happened is I had Avast Antivirus installed and it prevented VS Code from updating. So I tried manually updating by reinstalling it and I think it ended up installing multiple versions. Then after I got rid of my antivirus it was messed up.

Comment: What are the versions numbers (open CMD and run `code --version`) that you see for each update? Do you have any extensions?

Comment: @nrofis Tried that and I got `1.52.1
ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523
x64`... IDK what it means. This is before restarting to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the official [November 2020](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52) (version 1.52.x *which you currently have installed according to your comment*) as well as the [July 2020](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_48) (version 1.48) update and not in one of them is anything similar mentioned.

Exactly the contrary: In the past there were suggestions to implement a feature to [downgrade](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/601456/how-can-i-downgrade-to-the-prior-version-of-vs-201.html) or just in general [roll back](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/395028/introduce-the-ability-to-roll-back-a-visual-studio.html) to a prior Visual Studio version, though these requests have generally been dismissed and an alternative solution, namely uninstalling re-installing the wanted version, has mostly been suggested by the team. On a slight off-topic note, the Visual Studio Team has also declared it would be completely inefficient to implement such a rollback feature:

> From a tech standpoint, we've talked about what implementing "rollback" would take. We think that if we were to implement rollback, to make it a 100% rollback and "correct", it would likely be a **lot slower** [...]

*[Quote](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/847710/view.html) from User [@artl](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/users/731/87a5fc89-dac5-4ba3-b91f-de3a93058c32.html) in the [Visual Studio Developer Community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/).*

To conclude these different sources and information, **I highly doubt it's an intentional feature** of VS.

---

> How can I prevent this from happening?

What can you do if you got a problem with an installation/update issue? Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019) for the official documentation. I would especially suggest **Step 2** ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) is a more in-depth tutorial on how to repair Visual Studio), **Step 4** and **Step 6**.

As a last resort you might need to [uninstall Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and re-install it with the [latest version](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), namely the [November 2020](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52) update.

---

As this is not a known bug, at least not to my knowledge - and I've done some digging in the forum; the only thing coming close to the issue is [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1182334/view.html):

> [...] After installing update, it still displays the update notification,
> telling, that I still have version 15.9.26, although About box tells
> 15.9.27. [...]

I suggest to report the issue in the forum by clicking `Report a problem` on the [start page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: The issue is, the info you gave me is for VS Code 2019, and I am using VS Code 2020...

Comment: @M-Chen-3 As mentioned in my reply, though it’s supposed to function as an example that they haven’t implemented such a feature yet (or won’t ever).

Comment: My issue hasn't been resolved yet, but I've reported it and hopefully the developers will get back to me soon! Thanks for the information!